# Apex, HttpRequest, Named Credentials

Tags: apex, api, httprequest, security-token

i have to make an httpRequest with apex to an external site.

Problem:

- I have to securely store an API Key somewhere in salesforce so that it's possible to use in apex
- The header of the request must contain the key 'access-token' with the key as the value
- no CPQ, so Merged Fields from named credentials don't seem to work
- only administrator right for an enterprise edition.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Named Credentials allow using custom headers while making API calls from Apex. Are you saying this is not working?

Comment: There are pre-defined authentication methods and none of them fits the fairly simple one i described above.

Comment: Are you using OAuth based or Password based authentication?

Comment: None of them. I use a simple secret api key that is included in the header as ```'access-token: <key>'```. And thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this. It is not an elegant way to solve this problem, but perhaps it should work.

1. Create a Named Credential.
2. Select Identity Type as "Named Principle".
3. Authentication Protocol as "Password Authentication".
4. Write any meaningful Username and paste your access-token in the "Password" field.
5. Disable"Generate Authorization Header" and enable "Allow Merge Fields in HTTP Header" in the Callout Options

In the Apex class:

```
req.setEndpoint('callout:namedCredentialName');
req.setHeader('access-token', '{!$Credential.Password}');
```

Comment: I had the same idea. But i didn't disable ```Generate Authorization Header```, so i give it another shot. Thanks!

Comment: Please select it as an answer if it works.

Comment: Do you know a way to view the request header? debuging in salesforce won't work because merge fields are not yet replaced with the actual values from the named credential in the HTTPRequest object

Comment: It worked. The rest API i was calling was buggy